# Does someone know why the image doesn't get uploaded

Tags: php, image, upload

As title says, does someone know why the image doesn't get uploaded?
I'm trying to make a propic image upload page but image doesn't get uploaded.

This is the HTML form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="../php/modifica-profilo.php">
<!-- other inputs -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Immagine profilo</label>
    <input type="file" name="propic" class="form-control-file" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg">
    <small class="form-text text-muted">Solo immagini .png e .jpg - Dimensione massima 4 MB</small>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="dettagliBtn">Salva modifiche</button>
</div>
```

And this is the php script part "modifica-profilo.php":

```
if(!empty($_POST['propic'])){
            $dimensioneFile = $_FILES['propic']['size'];
            $tipoFile = $_FILES['propic']['type'];
            $tmp_name = $_FILES['propic']['tmp_name'];

            $dir = "../img/propic-utenti/";

            $estensione = image_type_to_extension(IMAGETYPE_PNG);
            $estensione = image_type_to_extension(IMAGETYPE_JPEG);

            $propic = md5($uid).$estensione;

            if($dimensioneFile > 4000000){
                echo "Il file è troppo grande";
            }else{
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$dir.$propic);
            }
        }else{
            $prendoPropic = "SELECT propic FROM clienti WHERE id='$uid';";
            $rpp = $conn->query($prendoPropic);
            $p = $rpp->fetch_assoc();

            if($p['propic'] == "p-default.png"){
                $propic = "p-default.png";
            }else{
                $propic = $p['propic'];
            }
        }

        $aggiornodb = "UPDATE clienti SET cognome='$cognome', nome='$nome', email='$email', propic='$propic' WHERE id='$uid';";
        $risultato = $conn->query($aggiornodb);
```

Comment: Have you get some errors? are the data saved correctly in the database?

Comment: no errors, all data gets saved on db except for propic

Comment: You have to check if $_FILES['propic'] is empty or not

Comment: I dont recommend the Question title, we can imagine what others will input in their search engine so they can find this kind of reference.

Comment: Also check if  move_uploaded_file()  return true or false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because, `$_POST['propic']` will always been empty,
this should be `$_FILES['propic']`

You better use this

```
if(!empty($_POST['dettagliBtn'])){
//since you only have 1 data on $_POST which is the button. Because you have given it a name attribute.
```

Instead of this

```
if(!empty($_POST['propic'])){
// this will always get false
```

Make sure also, the submit button is inside your form.

Comment: I check the button at file start

Comment: now, propic name gets saved on database, but image still not gets saved on folder

Comment: The image doesn't saves in the folder because you check the input in the wrong way, as @Jovylle Bermudez says you have to check  if(!empty($_FILES['propic']){ instead of $_POST['propic']

Comment: @Sfili_81 I did, still nothing ->  if(!empty($_FILES['propic'])){

Comment: Since you can now proceed on the submission, can you trace it again. You might get it work this time.